# How make VStudio test-explorer build only projects with tests

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nunit

I am using Visual Studio Proffesion 2013 to run NUnit tests from the integrated test-explorer.  It all works, well except that test discovery builds every project in the solution, including some fairly slow ones.

The behaviour I want is:

- I tell Vstudio which Projects contain NUnit tests (or it figures it out automatically from source).
- Vstudio builds those projects and all their dependencies.
- Vstudio lets NUnit do its test discovery on those Projects.
- Vstudio runs all those tests, displaying results in the test Explorer.

How do I acheive something like that?  Talks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx about `.runsettings`  and `.testsettings` files, but I don't know how to create those.  Also I don't know if they are relevant for NUnit.